# NHibernate performance: Session.Criteria vs LINQ in-memory

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

What results in the best performance when needing a dataset according to a complex criteria? There are two choices: create a complex ICriteria or Session.Linq statement, OR use LINQ from a root object and let NHibernate handle the lazy loading.

Option 1 (using Session):

```
var result = Session.Linq<Contractor>().Where(contractor => contractor.account == "bla@account.com)
//....
.Where(condition => condition.Orders.Any(condition))
//... more conditions
```

Option 2 (use root object to do "in-memory" querying, which might mean that a large result set will be pulled from the SQL server):

```
var contractor = Session.Linq<Contractor>().Single(c => c.Id == 1);

contractor.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.NestedCollection)
.Where(c => c.List.Any(condition))
.Where(//..... more complex filtering;
```

The in-memory variant does not generate warnings in NHPRof, however, the Session variant generates the warning that too many joins might bog performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends, but generally it's best to let the database do its job and eagerly fetch what you know you'll need. An exception to this is [fetching multiple associations](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/16/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate.aspx).